# How can I capture dynamic value in Load Runner that appears in the Request header section?

Tags: testing, scripting, performance-testing, loadrunner

A **dynamic value that appears in the subsequent web requests appears in the Request Header throughout the script**. I am unable to correlate this value as it is not available in response header / body section. How can I now correlate this value?

I have tried recording using VUGEN - HTML & URL Mode. I have also used Fiddler as well as HAR files exported via Chrome Developer Tools. None of them have any additional request/responses that could have been potentially missed while recording with VUGen or other tools.

The dynamic value appears in the Request Header like this :

**Reference:**

```
https://*****/suite/sites/ecase-case-worker/page/home/start-process/iUBVQU4qoHEAl9UkPVyXKjTxMt3bz-olj7yCJ6dulSOHbmIIDal?parameters=**855b2a7b-a175-49e6-9ee0-7b7f37667197**
```

The "855b2a...." value appears throughout the script in different places like this below :-

```
web_custom_request("iUBVQU4qoHEAl9UkPVyXKjTxMt3bz-olj7yCJ6dulSOHbmIIDal", 
        "URL=https://****/suite/rest/a/sites/latest/ecase-case-worker/page/home/startProcess/iUBVQU4qoHEAl9UkPVyXKjTxMt3bz-olj7yCJ6dulSOHbmIIDal?cacheKey=**855b2a7b-a175-49e6-9ee0-7b7f37667197**",
```

I have manually verified in the application that it this value keeps changing every single time "Create application" link is clicked. Is there a way to capture this dynamically changing value?

Comment: This value must appear somewhere in the response otherwise you won't be able to send it in your request. You cannot generate it by yourself. Have you checked the complete traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fiddler recording helped in identifying the correlation value as it was hidden in one of the EXTRARES references, which wasn't captured anywhere by the VUGen. The request had to be subsequently added manually into the script to pick up the dynamic value in it's response.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not sent to you from the server, as a correlated value, then what remains is that the value is generated on the client, likely as a part of a JavaScript function output.

Speak with the developer of your application about the location of the generation of this value.  If it is locally generated then simply execute the JavaScript inside of your HTTP script or reproduce the algorithm in C for native inclusion in a C HTTP virtual user.   You have some alternate paths as well, which includes the newer JavaScript based virtual user, Truclient (which runs a full browser), Citrix, RDP or GUI virtual users.

With Truclient, Citrix, RDP or GUI you are simply going to run a full browser and inherit the JavaScript execution and inclusion of the key value as a part of full stack execution.